# How to build an rdf file using an xml file as input

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I have an input file in xml format and I need to convert it into a .rdf file that is based on an ontology model created.

Can anyone let me know what the suitable method is to do this using jena api in java?

Answer (score 2):

Is your input file in some arbitrary XML format, or is it already serialized as `RDF/XML`? (ie: is the root tag of your document `<rdf:RDF>`?)

If it is in some arbitrary format, then you will need to define some rdf-based schema for representing your data. This is purely project-specific, and will require work on your part to define a way for a graph to apply to your data.

Once you have done that, then basic document construction is a topic for the [Jena Tutorials](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/). There is far too much material to cover here, but the basics of creating a statement should suffice:

```java
final Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
final Resource s = m.createResource("urn:ex:subject");
final Property p = m.createProperty("urn:ex:predicate");
final Resource o = m.createResource("urn:ex:object");
m.add(s,p,o);
try( final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.createTempFile("tmp","rdf"), StandardOpenOptions.CREATE_NEW) ){
   m.write(out, null, "RDF/XML");
}
```

The exercise of iterating over your XML and constructing the proper set of statements is left as an exercise for the reader.

If your data is already in `RDF/XML`, then you can directly [read it in to a model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/):

```java
// Assume you have an InputStream called 'in' pointing at your input data
final Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); 
m.read(in, null, "RDF/XML"); // Assumed that there is no base
```

Comment: the input file is not serialized as RDF/XML , it is in XML format only.Actually i am very new to this so can you please tell me how to use this file to represent any in-memory ontology model?

Comment: You'll need to use some form of XML parsing and traversal (DOM/SAX/etc) to ingest the input file. It ends up being up to you in terms of how to interpret the data. For example, encountering a `<person name="bill">` tag in XML may mean that there is a person in your domain whose name is Bill. In RDF, you may then decide to create two statements: `myprefix:Bill rdf:type foaf:Person`, `myprefix:bill foaf:name "Bill"^^xsd:string`. You may wish to review several RDF tutorials in order to familiarize yourself with the use of a graph to express your data.

Comment: Can you give provide some links which would be helpful.Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you are new to XML parsing, I'd go with something simple like [DOM Parsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html). Once you can traverse your XML document, I'd dig into the [Apache Jena Tutorials](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/). If the answer/comments answered your question to your satisfaction, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).